# tao_idl -Gstl doesn't map std::string

Tags: c++, opendds

I'm using opendds and tao/ace to generate code from an idl file.

My idl file:

```
struct SSave
{
    string strr;
};
```

I generate the code like so:

```
opendds_idl Class.idl 
tao_idl -Gstl -I/usr/include/ Class.idl 
tao_idl -Gstl -I/usr/include/ ClassTypeSupport.idl
#-Gstl Generate the alternate C++ mapping for IDL strings and sequences
```

And here's what I got in the file ClassC.h for example:

```
#include <vector>    
#include <string> //inclusion of string
{...}
struct  SSave
{

    // TAO_IDL - Generated from
    // /build/opendds-3.13/ACE_TAO/TAO/TAO_IDL/be/be_type.cpp:304
    typedef SSave_var _var_type;
    typedef SSave_out _out_type;

    static void _tao_any_destructor (void *); 

    ::TAO::String_Manager strr; //NOT std::string
};
{...}
```

So is there a way to tell TAO to map std::string instead of ::TAO::String_Manager?

Note: I'm using version 2.5.1 of tao_idl.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenDDS follows the IDL to C++ language mapping, there a IDL string is mapped to its own specific type (as tao_idl generates). As part of [AXCIOMA](http://www.axcioma.org) we have implemented the [IDL to C++11](https://www.omg.org/spec/CPP11) language mapping for DDS which will support OpenDDS in the next major release.

Btw, you already asked [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/opendds/mailman/message/36427090/) on the OpenDDS mailing list and got a response there.